# SQL: IF NOT EXISTS INSERT then UPDATE

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I know there are a lot of posts on this subject but this is slightly different. I have 2 tables `variant_detail (vad)` and `variant_external_analysis (vaea)`.  `vaea` is mainly empty and I need to update it for all lines in `vad`. If I insert in `vaea` and the line already exists the it duplicates the line and so breaks the database.

In testing on 1 line I have solved the problem with:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT vaea_vad_id FROM variant_external_analysis 
            JOIN variant_detail ON vad_id = vaea_vad_id 
            WHERE vad_variant_code = 16469)
BEGIN
    INSERT variant_external_analysis (vaea_vad_id) 
    SELECT vad_id
    FROM variant_detail
END

UPDATE variant_external_analysis

SET vaea_last_amended_on = GETDATE(), vaea_last_amended_by = 13, vaea_n_1 = 1

FROM variant_external_analysis
JOIN variant_detail ON vad_id = vaea_vad_id

WHERE vad_variant_code = 16469
```

This works perfectly UNTIL I remove the WHERE statements so that it effects the whole table. The code below UPDATEs correctly but now no longer INSERTS

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT vaea_vad_id FROM variant_external_analysis

JOIN variant_detail ON vad_id = vaea_vad_id 

            WHERE vad_id = vaea_vad_id)
BEGIN
    INSERT variant_external_analysis (vaea_vad_id) 
    SELECT vad_id
    FROM variant_detail
END

UPDATE variant_external_analysis

SET vaea_last_amended_on = GETDATE(), vaea_last_amended_by = 13, vaea_n_1 = 1

FROM variant_external_analysis
JOIN variant_detail ON vad_id = vaea_vad_id
```

I am probably missing something simple.

Comment: which DBMS product are you using? ("SQL" is just a query language not a product name)

Comment: Is this a one time thing or something that will be done frequently?

Comment: This is called `MERGE` in Standard SQL, most DBMSes support it.

Comment: T-SQL, it is part of a session that runs every 10 mins to update prices on over 100K rows of products

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code looks pretty similar to T-SQL so here is an example how to do it using [MERGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) in MS SQL Server:

```
merge variant_external_analysis vea
--using here left join (along with where condition) we'll get only rows 
--that are in variand_details but aren't in variant_external_analysis
using(select vd.vad_id 
  from variant_detail vd
  left join variant_external_analysis vaea on vd.vad_id = vaea.vaea_vad_id 
  where vaea.id is null) t --or any another column of vaea
on (vea.vaea_vad_id = t.vad_id)
when not matched then 
    insert (vaea_vad_id, vaea_last_amended_on, vaea_last_amended_by, vaea_n_1)
    values(t.vad_id, getdate(), 13, 1)
;
```

**UPD**
To test clause with a single row:

1. add a `code` as a return column in a `using` clause
2. extend a `when` clause with a `code` condition

---

```
merge variant_external_analysis vea
    --using here left join (along with where condition) we'll get only rows 
    --that are in variand_details but aren't in variant_external_analysis
    using(select vd.vad_id, vd.vad_variant_code 
      from variant_detail vd
      left join variant_external_analysis vaea on vd.vad_id = vaea.vaea_vad_id 
      where vaea.id is null) t --or any another column of vaea
    on (vea.vaea_vad_id = t.vad_id)
    when not matched and t.vad_variant_code = 16469 then 
        insert (vaea_vad_id, vaea_last_amended_on, vaea_last_amended_by, vaea_n_1)
        values(t.vad_id, getdate(), 13, 1)
    ;
```

Comment: That looks good, but i am nervous to try it without testing it on 1 row first.

Comment: I have never used MERGE before, where do I add in the WHERE vad_variant_code = 101 so it will only check and INSERT on the 1 test row.

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example for a single row

Comment: That works great to replace the INSERT part. But when run with the UPDATE section added below it doesn't update anymore? The vaea_n_1 = 1 is actually vaea_n_1 = a 20 line equation of sql to produce the updated price of the product

Comment: then wrap this 20 lines into a function and replace a hardcoded `1` with a `UDF` invocation

Comment: Thank you this was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You have "vad_variant_code = vad_id = vaea_vad_id" in you where clause.

Comment: sorry that was a mistype